# Change the Product grid view to a specific number of columns

Tags: magento2, product, product-list, category-products

The default number of columns is 3.  How do I change it to 2?  I prefer a solution that uses the admin, but I will settle for any solution.  I have looked through the Magento user guide www.magento.com/help/documentation.  I am using Magento (Commerce)ver. 2.3.0.

I have tried:
 In the Custom Design tab for a category, enter this code in the Custom Layout Update field:

`<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><count>2</count></action>
</reference>`

It had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

you can manage the product listing width from below file

> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/module/_listings.less

change the width attribute in product-item class

Note : Override the above file according to Magento standard.